Mixed Linear Model R2 and ICC calculation using Python statsmodels
I'm new to mixed linear models. I built a model with two random effects (Student_id and Subject) and one fixed effect (MAI), with the predicted variable being SRL.
model = mixedlm("SRL ~ MAI", data=df, groups=df["Student_id"], re_formula="~1", vc_formula={"Subject": "0 + C(Subject)"})
result = model.fit()

I want to decompose the variance, to calculate how much variance is explained by each effect. That is:

marginal $R^2$ (i.e. $R^2_M$, variance explained by fixed effects)
conditional $R^2$ (i.e. $R^2_C$ variance explained by fixed + random effects)
ICC for Student_id (i.e. $ICC_1$, part of random effect)
ICC for Subject (i.e. $ICC_2$, part of random effect)

After researching and viewing this question, I find that five of the below calculations are relevant:
var_f_r = result.fittedvalues.var() # fixed and random effect variance? 0.26061471675794606
var_f = result.predict(result_df).var() # fixed effect? 0.11
var_e = result.scale # residual variance, 0.09
var_r1 = result.cov_re.iloc[0, 0] # random effect for Student_id, 0.129
var_r2 = result.vcomp[0] # random effect for Subject, 0.079

I would do something like this, but it doesn't seem correct:
$total\_var = var\_f + var\_e + var\_{r1} + var\_{r2}$
$R^2_M = \frac{var\_f}{total\_var}$
$R^2_C = \frac{var\_f\_r}{total\_var}$
$ICC_1 = \frac{var\_r1}{total\_var}$
$ICC_2 = \frac{var\_r2}{total\_var}$
Questions:

Can you point out where my understanding may be incorrect, and tell me how to calculate it correctly?
If we change it to a null model mixedlm("SRL ~ 1", data=df, groups=df["Student_id"], re_formula="~1", vc_formula={"Subject": "0 + C(Subject)"}). Can we do the calculation in the same way (var_f is 0 in this case)

Appreciate your help!
